# homework: simple linked list

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I have problems with my homework.
I want to read from a file, save it in a struct as a simple linked list and print all nodes on the display.
I don't know why, but it shows me only the first node.
Is someone here who can help me? I don't get errors with my code.

MyCode:

Comment: In `else` path of `while-loop` part of function `artikelAusDateiLesen()` you create a new list entry but you don't append it to list represented by list head `w`. If list is not empty you first need to search last list entry and store pointer to last list entry as e.g. `tail`. Then create new list entry and link it to `tail->next`. BTW the actions you take in `if` and `else` path are almost the same (create new entry and assign data). Thus independent of if list is empty or not first identify list tail and after that create and link new entry.

Comment: zeigeAlleWaren receives a pointer w , then you have ptr=w , then at the end you have ptr= ptr->next; Could it be, you wanted to say ptr->next=ptr ?

Comment: @MathiasSchmid im searching the last entry with the while loop in the else part.

Comment: Right, but your search is running behind list tail and after that you create a list entry which won't be linked which results in memory leaks. BTW you don't free the memory for list at the end of `main()`.

Comment: @jomes Where is the code?